# How does じろじろ suggest staring?

Tags: etymology, sound-symbolism

What is the origin of the mimetic term じろじろ?  As in じろじろ見ないでください。 How does jirojiro mimic or suggest someone staring?

[This answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/90469/31807) mentions how anime characters will literally say this, but does not explain the ideographic connection to staring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word じろじろ is part of a cluster of related adverbs.

- [じろじろ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%98%E3%82%8D%E3%81%98%E3%82%8D-536287) -- First cited to 1700.  Found in some older texts as ぢろぢろ.
- [じろり](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%98%E3%82%8D%E3%82%8A-536416#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8) -- First cited to 1871.  Found in some older texts as ぢろり.
- じらり -- Date unknown.  No actual dictionary entry for this, although it is listed as a synonym in the [じろり entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%98%E3%82%8D%E3%82%8A-536416#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8).
- [じろっと](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%98%E3%82%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8-297390) -- First cited to 1903.  Found in some older texts as ぢろっと.

All of these have to do with "moving the eyes and staring pointedly".

I had first thought that maybe the じろ was a shift from しろ and had to do with the whites of the eyes somehow, and the voicing indicated a softer or rounder kind of motion.  However, the root is clearly ぢろ, not じろ.  I'm not sure how this sound symbolism plays out; the initial ぢ is certainly unusual.  It's possible that the initial ぢ arose as a kind of emphasis of じ, in which case this might still be related to the whites of the eyes, and / or to adverb じっと ("fixedly").

The ろ seems to be related to, or at least suggestive of, the ろ in adverbs like ぎょろぎょろ ("rollingly", as when rolling one's eyes) or ころころ ("rollingly", as when something rolls around).

Comment: Possibly related thread: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/96183/connection-between-phenomime-%e3%81%98-and-adverb-%e3%81%98%e3%81%a3-%e3%81%a8